# Tracking asynchronous search terms, refinements, and results

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I have an embedded Google Map with a custom search bar. Results are returned as you type (AJAX), in a dropdown menu (results are "locations", a mix of locations from our API and from Google's default map search).

I need to set up Google Analytics tracking for this search - so far, I've read that pushing a virtual pageview with the search term as a URL parameter (alongside GA's Site Search) seems to be the way to go.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/mysite/?q=searchterm');
```

However, I also want to track search refinements, as well as which result in the dropdown the user clicks.

How should I accomplish this with Google Analytics? I want the data to be neatly organized and easily analyzed.

*(assume that I already have the code implemented to detect refinements as well as result clicks)*